# how to get the integral boundaries for marginal integration?

Tags: probability

I have three inequality 
    $$0<Y_3<1$$
    $$-Y_2<Y_3<1-Y_2$$
    $$Y_1-Y_2-1<Y_3<Y_1-Y_2$$

I have the joint density $$f_{Y1},_{Y2},_{Y3}$$
I want to get $$f_{Y1},_{Y2}$$

i know that i have to integrate with respect to $Y_3$ but the problem for me is how to choose the boundaries of the integration.
I know that i have to get the max for the lower boundaries and the min for the upper but i can't do or solve it.
so any help quickly plz,thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding up the system of inequalities yet?

We have that

\begin{align*}
0&<y_3<1\\
-y_2&<y_3<1-y_2\\
y_1-y_2-1&<y_3<y_1-y_2
\end{align*}

And so adding the first two inequalities gives us

\begin{align*}
-y_2&<2y_3<2-y_2\\
y_1-y_2-1&<y_3<y_1-y_2
\end{align*}
And we can add these two inequalities to finally get
\begin{align*}
y_1-2y_2-1&<3y_3<y_1-2y_2+2
\end{align*}

And so we have that 
$$\frac{y_1-2y_2-1}{3}<y_3<\frac{y_1-2y_2+2}{3}$$

Now, if we want to marginalize out $y_3$ the problem becomes

$$f_{Y_1,Y_2}=\int_\frac{y_1-2y_2-1}{3}^\frac{y_1-2y_2+2}{3} f_{Y_1,Y_2}d_{Y_3}$$

Comment: No, i didn't try adding the inequality system, but i think this isn't the region boundaries if i graph the system.@RustyStatistician

Comment: Double check my math, but I'm pretty sure thats how you solve it,